# Regex: SQL-Query-String match * or .* but count(*)

Tags: php, mysql, regex

there is a query-string like this:

```
select a.* from a
select * from a
```

this should be NOT allowed and match!

BUT :-)

```
select count(*), a.id from a
select a.id, count( * ) from a
```

this should be allowed and don't match!

With my poor regex-knowledge I have the following regex...

```
\bselect\b.*?(\*|\.\*).*?(?=\bfrom\b)
```

This regex works fine with * or .* but I am still struggling around with the allowed "count(*)" field selection.

Regex is not the favored section and I tried to come clear about positive and negative LookBehinds/LookAHeads... This is still confusing me :-D

Are there any hints?

Comment: What are the rules for what should, shouldnt match? Regex is being used in PHP or mysql? Maybe `^\bselect[^,]+from.*$`?

Comment: Just so that it's understood correctly, this is to create an SQL parser using regex in PHP?

Comment: You are right. It's an SQL-Parser written in PHP.
I just want to prevent the damn * or .* ;-)

Comment: What about `select 6 * b from a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is pretty smart to prevent people from using `select * from ...` and its variations, because when the table is altered their queries are still working unless the required columns are affected, you have to be careful to not to be too restrictive.

This also checks in sub-queries:

```
\bselect(\s*\*\s*|.*\b[a-zA-Z_]\w*\s*\.\s*\*.*)from\b
```

It checks for the simple case `\bselect\s*\*\s*from\b` and for a valid table name followed by a `.*` again with optional whitespaces in between, but the latter can be anywhere in between `select` and `from`.

But it's never going to be perfect, e.g. this is a false positive:

```
select 'select * from ' || b from a
```